# Complex integration form question

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling to understand the following concept for the complex integration.

If a curve $c$ is a circle centred at $2i$ with a very small yet unspecified radius, how can it be $\int_{c}{\frac{1}{z+2i}} = 0$ and $\int_{c}{\frac{1}{z-2i}} = 2\pi{i}$?

My struggle comes from the fact that we do not know of the radius. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radius is small enough (less than $4$), then $-2i$ is outside the circle, so
$$
\frac{1}{z+2i}
$$
is holomorphic (on a neighborhood the disc bounded by $C$). Cauchy's integral theorem then shows that
$$
\int_C \frac{1}{z+2i}\,dz = 0.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\int_C \frac{1}{z-2i}\,dz = 2\pi i
$$
independently of the radius of $C$, either by direct parametrization or using Cauchy's integral formula applied to the entire function $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you kindly elaborate on the direct parametrisation method without using the Cauchy's integral formula?